# iPhone: Fixed position Div invisible

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I have a Joomla 3 site at http://www.getdripped.com/dev which I am building a mobile menu for. I have it working well on desktops, but when I try to view it on my iPhone the menu slides in but is invisible. I can still blindly tap and the links do work, but its completely invisible. What's even weirder, when I click the button again to close the menu, it suddenly shows up for a brief second before the drawer closes. I'm not sure what the problem is, can anyone help?

My iPhone is running iOS 8.2, and I previewed in Safari. When I preview in the iPhone Chrome app, everything works swimmingly. Very confused here...

Comment: You're right, it flashes when you close it. Weird, I'll see if I can think of anything

Comment: Thanks for checking it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is very similar to other issues seen in iOS 8. A variation of the  `-webkit-transform` hack seems to solve this problem as well.

Adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the `body.open` selector seems to solve the issue.

```
body.open {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

iOS 8 appears to have some layering issues which 3D transforms are able to counteract. This one appears to be related to the use of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` as the OP discovered.

Add this to the list of weird bugs in iOS 8.

Comment: That did the trick! Had to make some modifications because it pushed the menu up into the header. Thanks!

Comment: I want to make an amendment to my previous comment: while this did fix the initial problem, a little bit of digging found the root of this problem: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` I used this line on the menu to give it a more natural scroll feel on mobile. It looks to me as though this plays a pretty big part in the layering issues Alexander spoke of. Just a thought.

Comment: @NickWinner How strange. Thanks for the info, I'll add a note for future readers.